# Save/Load rpivottable configuration

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, rpivottable

I use rpivottable on several (rmarkdown) web pages.

I have seen [an example here](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/save_restore.html) of saving/restoring table configuration to/from cookie.
Since I am not good in javascript, I would like to ask if it is possible to programmatically add two buttons in the `rmd` page, on top of the table control, allowing the users to save/load their preferred table configurations (either to cookie, or to a local file, if possible). Could you provide sample code to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one took a while. I used local storage. I've got a lot of styling here, but it's unnecessary. I used the output of `flexdashboard`, since that tends to cause me the most problems with JS.

```
<style>
body {    /*push content away from far right and left edges*/
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.rpivotTable {
  overflow:auto;
  resize: both;
  box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 20px 50px 5px;
}
.btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: .5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em; 
  padding: .3em 0px;
  width: 18em;
  text-decoration: none; /*no underline!!*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active { /*simulate movement*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
</style>
```

I've used the content that I've found in other questions.

````
## R Markdown

<div style="margin-right:5%;">

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(10)`

</div>

```{r cars}

library(rpivotTable)

data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)[10] <- "George.Dontas"

```

Here is the **first** Div.

## Including Plots

Do you want to save or restore the previously saved pivot tables' configuration?

<a id='saveBtn' class='btn' style="background-color:#003b70;color:white;">Save Current Configuration</a>
<a id='restoBtn' class='btn' style="background-color:#b21e29;color:white;">Restore Previous Configuration</a>

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}
rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="George.Dontas", cols=c("cyl","carb"),width="100%", height="400px")
```

```{r morePressure, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}
rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="George.Dontas", cols=c("cyl","carb"),width="100%", height="400px")
```

This should be a different aspect of the report.

```{r evenMorePressure, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}
rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="George.Dontas", cols=c("cyl","carb"),width="100%", height="400px")
```
````

Here is the JS/JQuery...it's a bit ugly and a rather unseemly hodgepodge of the two (JS/JQuery).

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="as-is",engine="js"}

// save current state of the tables to my browser
setTimeout(function(){       //add the events first
  document.querySelector('a#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', savoring);
  document.querySelector('a#restoBtn').addEventListener('click', giveItBack);
  function savoring() {                             // function to save
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    for(i=0; i < el.length; i++){
      elId = el[i].getAttribute("id");
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions"); // collect rows/columns filters
      delete stringy['aggregators'];                 // remove the arbitrary
      delete stringy['renderers'];
      stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);            // make it one key:value
      window.localStorage.setItem('table' + i, stringy2); // store it!
    }
  };
  function giveItBack() {                           // function to regurgitate
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    console.log("working on the giver");
    ods = [...el[0].ownerDocument.scripts];         // make it an array
    for(j=0; j < el.length; j++){
      elId = el[j].getAttribute("id");
      where = ods.filter(function(ods){             // filter scripts for table data
        return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
      })[0].innerHTML; 
      where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;            // WOOO HOO! I figured it out!!
      where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2);   // finally sheesh!!
      gimme = window.localStorage.getItem('table' + j); // get storage
      $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, JSON.parse(gimme), true, "en"); // put it back!
    }
  }
},100);

```
````

[image]

---

---

#### Update

Thanks for pointing out some opportunities for improvement, @George Dontas. This update changes how the configuration is saved. I'm sure there are still ways to improve it, though.

This update adds the file or webpage name as part of the key-value pair used to store the information. Now, both the name of the webpage/script and table number need to match for the tables to update. Additionally, this will alert the user when a configuration cannot be restored. This alert would occur if there is nothing saved and if there is no file name and table matching configuration saved.

##### Updates to Saving the Configuration

There is one new line and one modified line of code in `savoring()`.

New:

```
path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //f name
```

Modified:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(path + '_table' + i, stringy2); // store it
```

The entire function with changes:

```
  function savoring() {                     // function to save
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0];
    for(i=0; i < el.length; i++){
      elId = el[i].getAttribute("id");
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions"); // collect filters
      delete stringy['aggregators'];        // remove the arbitrary
      delete stringy['renderers'];
      stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);   // make it one key:value
      window.localStorage.setItem(path + '_table' + i, stringy2);  // store it
    }
  };
```

##### Updates to Restoring the Configuration

There are few new lines in this function. The name has to be collected, as in the `savoring()` changes. Additionally, this function now has an alert for the user.

> I started out with the basic system alert, but it wasn't up to snuff for my tastes, so I also developed a custom alert box. I've included both here.

###### Basic Alert and Updated Configuration Retrieval

The only thing that changes from my original answer to making a basic alert are the following lines of code within the `giveItBack()` function:

```
path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //f name
```

and

```
  if(window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_table' + j) === null) {
    jj = j + 1;
    alert("WARNING: There is no saved pivot table configuration for " + path + "'s table " + jj + ".");
    continue; // don't update, go to next table (if more than 1)
  }
```

Here is the complete `giveItBack()` function (note that `notice(msg)` and `msg` are here, but commented out):

```
function giveItBack() {               // function to regurgitate
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    console.log("working on the giver");
    ods = [...el[0].ownerDocument.scripts];   // make it an array
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //name
    for(j=0; j < el.length; j++){
      elId = el[j].getAttribute("id");
      where = ods.filter(function(ods){     // filter scripts data
        return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
      })[0].innerHTML; 
      where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;    // WOOO HOO! I figured it out!!
      where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2); // finally formatted
      // is there a saved configuration that matches this file and table?
      if(window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_table' + j) === null) {
        jj = j + 1;
                  //this is for the standard alert box
        alert("WARNING: There is no saved pivot table configuration for " + path + "'s table " + jj + ".");
        //msg = "<b>WARNING</b><br><br>There is no saved pivot table configuration for<br>" + path + "."
        //notice(msg); //this is for the custom alert box
        continue; // go to next loop
      }
      gimme = window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_table' + j); // get storage
      $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, JSON.parse(gimme), true, "en"); // put it back!
    }
  };
```

[image]

###### Custom Alert and Updated Configuration Retrieval

If you choose to use a more custom approach to the alert message, there is a lot more (luckily, it should be copy and paste). You will use the `giveItBack` function from the updates for the basic alert, but comment out or delete `alert(...` and uncomment `msg` and `notice()`.

> For the CSS in my original answer, update the styles for `.btn` to  `.btn, #noted` and `.btn:active` to `btn:active, #noted:active`.

This is the remaining CSS for the custom alert. You can add this CSS to the other style tags or keep them separated.

```
<style>
#notice-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000000;
  background: transparent;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
#notice-box {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: .5px solid black;
  width = 300px;
  background: #003b70;
  color: white;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
#notHead {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2.5em;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#noted {
  background: #b21e29;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 120px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

The JS for the custom alert box is next. I placed this function within the `setTimeout(function(){` with `savoring()` and `giveItBack()`.

```
  function notice(msg) {
    function cr() {
      if(document.querySelector('#notice-wrapper') === null) {
          wrapper = document.createElement('div');
          wrapper.id = 'notice-wrapper';
          html = "<div id='notice-box'><h2 id='notHead'></h2><div id='noticeBtns'>";
          html += "<button id='noted'>OK</button></div></div>";
          wrapper.innerHTML = html;
          document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
      }
      insta = document.querySelector('#notice-wrapper');
      placer(insta);
      return(insta);
    }
    function placer(insta) {
      wrapper = insta;
      winHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientheight;
      wrapper.style.height = winHeight + "px";
    }
    function showy(el) {
      el.style.display = "block";
      el.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    function goAway(el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        el.style.display = "none";
      }, 1000);
    }
    function takeAction(msg) {
      insta = cr();
      insta.querySelector('#notHead').innerHTML = msg;
      showy(insta);
      insta.querySelector('#noted').addEventListener('click', function() {
        goAway(insta);
      }, false);
    }
    takeAction(msg);
  }
```

Of course, with this custom option, you have the opportunity to style it as you see fit. Style control isn't an option with the system alert messaging system.

[image]

Comment: You still have an unanswered question! I haven't gotten back to you on a resizing method for an expanding table. :)

Comment: Correct! Now I have two more questions:    
1. How querySelector should be defined, if I use <button> instead of <a>? I.e.  `<button id='saveBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save Current Configuration</button>`. I tried `'button#saveBtn'` with no luck.
2. I noticed that the configuration of all tables in the page is saved and retrieved. What is going to happen if I press "Restore" in another page that contains completely different tables?

Comment: Hmm. I think I answered the first one. I used `getElementById("saveBtn")`.

Comment: When it comes to using a button tag versus an anchor tag, it can come to an opinion. However, if the button is an anchor, I prefer an anchor tag. If you're using a form button, it will probably be an input tag. For your other question—right now, if you were to load a different script or different data tables, it would clear out any rows and columns designation. Your tables would still work. However, it wouldn't tell you what went wrong or why it happened. You found all sorts of holes here! I've got an update I'm about to add to my answer that addresses and fixes some potential problems.

Comment: A potential improvement: If you ask for the [subtotals renderers](https://nagarajanchinnasamy.github.io/subtotal/examples/): `rpivotTable(..., rendererName = "Table With Subtotal", subtotals = TRUE)` you will notice that they are not being restored. 
And something I was always curious about: Can subtotals and [TSV export](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/mps_export.html) be [available at the same time?](https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/98#issuecomment-482596575)

Comment: I added another answer—not for reputation, crazy! I've made a few changes to my `rpivotTable` repo... the new answer assumes you're using it. You wanted the option of a `tsv` render? Added to the function `rpivotTable`.  D3 sizing? Do that with the updated repo, as well. The save/retrieve cookie-ish is fixed—that's in the new answer. (That's no where near ready for the package!)

Comment: I didn't intend to speak (and cause any more trouble), but I have to say this. 
Your hard work here shouldn't go to waste. If it's not possible to add those two buttons in the pivotui, add your code in the README file of your GitHub repo too. And please do whatever it takes to replace the abandoned "official" version on CRAN with yours. We owe you a big thank you. :) ♥

Answer (score 0):

Don't mark up this answer—it's not another answer—it's an update. (And written for anyone who might read it; not just who asked...)

This updated method of saving and restoring table configuration is based on the modified version of the package `rpivotTable` (in Github: `fraupflaume/rpivotTable`).

> I've kept this answer self-contained so that you would not have to look at the other answer to assemble the code.

- This works for one to many `rpivotTable` widgets in the same RMarkdown rendered webpage.
- **Dynamic Sizing**: This script includes dynamic resizing, limited by the available width of the webpage (it will not overlap other content, and it *will not* make the webpage wider). For dynamic sizing to work—

  - If you use the output `html_document`, you have to unset the max-width of the class `main-container`. This setting creates massive margins, which is anti-conducive to this widget.
  - You need to style the class `.rpivotTable` with `overflow: auto`; you cannot assign `resize` to this class.
  - If you use the output `flex_dashboard`, you cannot leave the default setting `vertical-scroll: fit` (the opposite of dynamic sizing!)
  - You cannot set the default height and width of the widget at the widget level. Setting this makes the size *utterly* static.
  - It is perfectly acceptable to set the height and width of the table with static or dynamic sizes when creating the table (`rpivotTable()`).
  - What did I forget?
- **Cookie-ish Alert**: The configuration save has two options for rendering an alert (alert that indicates there was no data to restore).

  - System Alert: If using the system alert there are two lines of Javascript in the cookie function. The rest of the Javascript and CSS related to the alert is for the custom alert option.
  - Custom Alert: I'm going to touch on this from two perspectives: the CSS and the JS.

    - CSS: The only *required* CSS is ensuring the pop-up alert ack button has the style `cursor: pointer`. I *believe* that styling beyond that is strictly preference. The CSS that is related to the alert includes the following classes and ids: `#noted`, `#notice-wrapper`, `notice-box`, and `notHead`.
    - JS: There are just a few lines of JS in the cookie-ish function, `giveItBack`. The `notice` function for the alert box.
- **Cookie-ish vs. `subtotal`**: The fix for this issue (and what would have been an issue with `tsv`) required a few additional lines of code in the cookie-ish function, `giveItBack`. `savoring` did not change.
- **Cookie-ish Alignment**: Currently, the configuration is identified by the name of the file or webpage and by iteration (when you have more than one table, the order in which they appear by index). Consider the impact of reordering tables or renaming the file/page.

#### Dynamic Sizing Chunk

This chunk can go anywhere in your script; assumed: `echo=FALSE` is default, or the output option hides echoes.

````
```{r spicy, engine="js", include=FALSE, results="asis"}

scrp = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/1.2.3/ElementQueries.min.js",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/1.2.3/ResizeSensor.js"];

setTimeout(function(){ // this function adds the URLs to the HTML <head>
  for(i=0; i < scrp.length; i++) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scrp[i];
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
  ElementQueries.listen(); // just listen!!
}, 200); //wait a sec!
```
````

#### The JS for the Cookie-ish and Alerts

There should be plenty of comments to decipher the basic idea of what this does.

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="asis",engine="js"}

// save current state of the tables to my browser
setTimeout(function(){
                       // add to buttons
  document.querySelector('a#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', savoring); 
  document.querySelector('a#restoBtn').addEventListener('click', giveItBack);
  function savoring() {                             // function to save
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    for(i=0; i < el.length; i++){
      elId = el[i].getAttribute("id");
      stringy = $('#' + elId).data("pivotUIOptions");  // collect rows/col filters
      delete stringy['aggregators'];                   // remove not-parse-friendly keys
      delete stringy['renderers'];
      stringy2 = JSON.stringify(stringy);              // one key:value pair for storage
      window.localStorage.setItem(path + '_table' + i, stringy2);  // STORE it!
    }
  };
  function giveItBack() {                           // function to regurgitate
    el = document.querySelectorAll('.rpivotTable');
    console.log("working on the giver");
    ods = [...el[0].ownerDocument.scripts];         // make it an array
    path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".").slice()[0]; //filename
    for(j=0; j < el.length; j++){
      elId = el[j].getAttribute("id");
      where = ods.filter(function(ods){             // filter scripts for data
        return ods.dataset['for'] === elId;
      })[0].innerHTML; 
      where2 = JSON.parse(where).x.data;            // format data for pivotUI()
      where3 = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(where2);   // ...still formatting
      if(window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_table' + j) === null) { // alert
    // basic system alert
        //jj = j + 1;                                                 
        //alert("WARNING: There is no saved pivot table configuration for " + path + "'s table " + jj + ".");
    // custom alert
        msg = "<b>WARNING</b><br><br>There is no saved pivot table configuration for<br>" + path + "."
        notice(msg);
    // Either Alert: from here on needed whether basic or custom alert
        continue;
      }
      gimme = window.localStorage.getItem(path + '_table' + j); // get storage
      gimmeMore = JSON.parse(gimme);                            // prepare for recall
      if(where.includes('"subtotals":true')){       // is the option 'subtotals' used?
        gimmeMore.renderers = $.pivotUtilities.subtotal_renderers;
        gimmeMore.dataClass = $.pivotUtilities.SubtotalPivotData;
      }; 
      if(where.includes('"tsv":true')){             // is the option 'tsv' used?
        gimmeMore.renderers = $.extend(gimmeMore.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers);
      };
      $('#' + elId).pivotUI(where3, gimmeMore, true, "en"); // put it back!
    }
  };
  function notice(msg) { // all of this is for the custom alert box 
    function cr() {
      if(document.querySelector('#notice-wrapper') === null) { // if an alert doesn't exist
          wrapper = document.createElement('div');
          wrapper.id = 'notice-wrapper';
          html = "<div id='notice-box'><h2 id='notHead'></h2><div id='noticeBtns'>";
          html += "<button id='noted'>OK</button></div></div>";
          wrapper.innerHTML = html;
          document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
      }
      insta = document.querySelector('#notice-wrapper'); // a container for the alert box 
      placer(insta);
      return(insta);
    }
    function placer(insta) { // make the size reasonable, based on viewing screen
      wrapper = insta;
      winHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientheight;
      wrapper.style.height = winHeight + "px";
    }
    function showy(el) {
      el.style.display = "block";  // keep the content confined; add a control
      el.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    function goAway(el) {          // use the control to hide the alert when ack
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        el.style.display = "none";
      }, 1000);
    }
    function takeAction(msg) { // use all of the above: make alert and render it
      insta = cr();
      insta.querySelector('#notHead').innerHTML = msg;
      showy(insta);
      insta.querySelector('#noted').addEventListener('click', function() {
        goAway(insta);
      }, false);
    }
    takeAction(msg); // pop-up ENGAGED
  }
},200); // give me a sec—my browser may be slow... or my widgets may be fast... or...

```
````

#### The CSS

This will not go into an R chunk. This is all of the CSS used in my example. I did not use an external style sheet, although that is a better practice.

This CSS controls the alert, the buttons used for saving and retrieving the configuration, along with body and margin styles. I have included the CSS to make the pivot tables pop out, but it is commented out (these are `/* CSS commenters */`). You can use/not use at your discretion.

```
<style>
body {    /*push content away from far right and left edges*/
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.main-container {
  max-width: unset; // remove default from RMD
}
.rpivotTable {
  overflow:auto; /*this is absolutely needed*/
  /*resize: both; <- cannot have this*/
  /*box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 20px 50px 5px;
  max-width: 1100px;*/
}
.btn, #noted {
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: .5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em; 
  padding: .3em 0px;
  width: 18em;
  text-decoration: none; /*no underline!!*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active, #noted:active { /*simulate movement*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
#notice-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000000;
  background: transparent;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
#notice-box {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: .5px solid black;
  width = 300px;
  background: #003b70;
  color: white;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
#notHead {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2.5em;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#noted {
  background: #b21e29;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 120px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

#### R <- that too... Well, the rest of the RMD...

Here is the code for the RMD I use as an example. The only thing that I didn't include are my version notes (at 16 now...).

````
---
title: "rpivottable_test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup,include=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r data,include=F}
# devtools::install_github("fraupflaume/rpivotTable")
library(rpivotTable)
data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)[10] <- "George.Dontas"
```

## Make it Interesting...or not

Do you want to save or restore the previously saved pivot tables' configuration?

<!--- cookie-ish's buttons --->
<a id='saveBtn' class='btn' style="background-color:#003b70;color:white;">Save Current Configuration</a>
<a id='restoBtn' class='btn' style="background-color:#b21e29;color:white;">Restore Previous Configuration</a>

```{r showMe, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}

rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="George.Dontas", cols = c("cyl"), width = "90%", height = "40%",
            rendererOptions = list(
              c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), 
                        data = list(labels = TRUE),
                        options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                       maintainAspectRatio = FALSE),
                        size = list(width = "600",
                                    height = "500")),
              d3 = list(size = list(width = "500", height = "500")))) 
```

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(3)`

## How about Another Table?

Tell me things. Make sure I am not going to overlap later. You better be listening!

```{r morePressure, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}

rp <- rpivotTable(mtcars, rows = c("mpg", "am"), cols = "cyl", 
                  width = "90%", height = "40%", subtotals = T,
                  tsv = T,
                  rendererOptions = list(
                    c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), # this works!!
                              data = list(labels = TRUE),
                              size = list(width = "600",
                                          height = "500"),
                              options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                             maintainAspectRatio = FALSE))))
rp
```

This should be *anywhere* other than here.

```{r itsMine, echo=FALSE, fig.show="hold"}

df1 <- data.frame(where = LETTERS[1:3], what = c(3.6, 5.6, 1.1))
x = rpivotTable(df1, width="80%", height="40%", 
                aggregatorName = "Count", 
                vals = "Sum", 
                cols = "where",   
                rows = "what", 
                rendererOptions = list(c3 = list(legend = list(show = FALSE), # this works!!
                                                 data = list(labels = TRUE),
                                                 size = list(width = "500",
                                                             height = "500"),
                                                 options = list(responsive = TRUE,
                                                                maintainAspectRatio = FALSE))))

x

```

Put something here
````

[image]

I only controlled `d3` size in the first table. The next image reflects the difference between control and uncontrolled Treemap sizing.

[image]

I zoomed out in my browser so I could see the limits of the second treemap:

[image]

While I tried to provide enough information that anyone who came across this Q&A could potentially use it, I anxiously await when the questioner finds a way to break it :)

Comment: I have a suggestion. Would you like to enable the [`Issues` tab](https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/github-issues/), on your rpivotttable repo, so that we can submit there any problems or ideas for improvement? I already have one :)

Comment: Added; give me your worst!